# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skfuzzy'

Tags: python, module, package

When I'm trying to import the 'skfuzzy' module, I get this error. I installed the scikit-fuzzy package and I can see it among installed packages (using the 'pip list' command). I tried installing and re-installing it several times with various commands ('pip install'; 'pip3 install'; 'pip3 -U install') but nothing helped. Other modules such as numpy and matplotlib work fine. Also, after the installation I get this warning:

"WARNING: The script f2py.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location."

Is this connected to my problem? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

According to the warning, try and do the following:

1. Windows + R
2. Type sysdm.cpl
3. Go to Advance Tab and click on Environment Variables
4. In User variables [preferably] click on PATH
5. Click on New and add `C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts` to PATH

This will add the scripts to your environment variables. Hope this helps!

Comment: I did it - the warning did indeed disappear, but sadly it didn't fix my problem. Edit: found another fix, thanks for answer.

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of python installed on your system?

Answer (score 0):

I installed the scikit-fuzzy using the "easy_install -U scikit-fuzzy" command instead of pip, and it did remove the error.